# Page Session Countdown Timer

Tags: countdown

I wrote a PHP code that kills the session after 5 minuets from creation.

I would like to display a timer in the corner of the page that shows the
user how many minutes:seconds till the session times out. Are there any good
examples out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

There you have a simple example showing how to use it:

```
var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear});
```

So now what we need is a UNIX timestamp (time when session will end). Then we can modify it like this:

```
var endOfSession = new Date(youtitmestamp * 1000); // timestamp is in seconds and we need miliseconds
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: endOfSession});
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: yes, how can I integrate it with the session time stored in server?

Comment: If you could create a code which kills the session after 5 minutes from creationg, you could easily calculate time left before end of session.

Comment: I can calculate that, but I don't know how to show that to user in a dynamic way, like your example. please help me, I am new to javascript, but I know PHP well enough.

Comment: I added an example to my answer ;)